Back button not working after history.push from message eventlistener (window.postmessage)
We have two types of pages on our website - react pages and iframe pages (in django template).
We are handling redirection from iframe pages to react pages through window.postMessage.
In django template javascript code:
window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(postData), "https://" + main_domain);

In react code:
let { name } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  function handleMessage(e, originName) {
    if (originName === "from_iframe1") {
      props.history.push("next_url1");
    } else if (originName === "from_iframe2") {
      props.history.push("next_url2");
    }
  }
  
  if (name === "react_url1") {
    window.addEventListener(
      "message",
      e => handleMessage(e, "from_iframe1"),
      false
    );
  } else if (name === "react_url2") {
    window.addEventListener(
      "message",
      e => handleMessage(e, "from_iframe2"),
      false
    );
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener(
      "message",
      e => handleMessage(e, "others"),
      false
    );
  }
}, [name]);

The problem is that the browser stack is behaving in a very weird manner. After first redirection, it takes 2 clicks to go back. Next, it takes 4 clicks and then 6 clicks.
On using history.replaceState, it works perfectly on first redirection. But after that, it goes back multiple pages instead of one.
Please let me know if there is any known solution to this problem or some other approach we can try. Also, please mention if there is any other information needed.

@Keith I have added better code example. We are calling window.removeEventListener in last else case.

Unfortunately your not removing anything, you need to keep a reference to what was added, check my answer.

Why you only add event listeners for "from_iframe1" and "from_iframe2", but only remove for "others"? You should also note that you are passing anonymous functions to window.addEventListener so you are losing the reference to the function to remove it later. We may need a bit more context. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

window.addEventListener( there is the opposite of this called removeEventListener, remove your event on the unmount callback of your useEffect Also worth pointing out React during dev mode will double render components, this also explains the multiple of 2..
Try the following modification.
let { name } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  function handleMessage(e, originName) {
    if (originName === "from_iframe") {
      props.history.push("next_url");
    }
  }

  //move function here so we can keep a reference.
  const msgEvt = e => handleMessage(e, "from_iframe");

  
  if (name === "current_url") {
    window.addEventListener("message", msgEvt, false);
  }

  //on component unmount, remove
  return () => window.removeEventListener("message", msgEvt);
  

}, [name]);

